# Excel says SUMIF formula I try to use to have too few arguments

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2019

I am trying to use the SUMIF-formula, but can't seem to work out how it works, and how it want me to input the formula.

The formula template is stated as:

```
=SUMIF(range criteria [sum_range])
```

I have the following (dummy) table I created] with the sole purpose to experiment and explore this function...

[image]

Now, naturally, I want to put semi-colon or coma between the parameters, but since they don't seem to work, and the template is without any commas I've ommitted them completly in the above screenshot (trying to use them gives me formula error)

I've tried to look up examples to this to no avail... I even tried to replace the criteria-parameter to a static value; "Apples", just for the sake of minimizing error-sources - also to no use.

What am I missing?

Comment: You definitely need something to separate arguments. And that something is the "string separator" defined in Windows' "regional settings"

Comment: Show an exact example of your formula and some sample data on how/what you try to sum. It's probably an easy fix ;)

Comment: @JvdV I already did that, just couldn't inline the picture, it's in the link (to imgur)!
Edit: just figured out how to embbed it, and fixed it.

Comment: @MátéJuhász that was it! Went to Regional Settings to find out what was set, and well... nothing was set, so I selected coma, and restarted Excel. Worked like a charm!

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Máté Juhász](https://superuser.com/users/427317/m%C3%A1t%C3%A9-juh%C3%A1sz) mentioned, this issue was due to incorretly set *List Separator* character in Windows' Regional Settings. I selected coma (which was the only choice in the drop-down menu), and restarted Excel.

Now it works like a charm!

[image]